# How do I reenable "open in new window" option in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

In Ubuntu 13.04, Nautilus no longer has an *Open in new window* option for folders, but only *Open in new tab*. How can I reenable that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new context menu for this by:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Then from the Dash Search run:
Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool

Define a new action (Click on the “+” in the menu bar)

Now Fill in the parameters in the Action Tab:

```
[x] Display Item in selection contextg menu
[x] Display item in location context menu
Context Label: “Open in New Window”
[x] Display item in the toolbar
[x] Use same label for icon in the toolbar
```

Now Fill in the parameters for the Command Tab:

```
Label: “New Window”
Path: “nautilus”
parameters: “%b”
Working directory: “%d”
```

Click on the Save icon.  You should now have a new context item:

```
“Nautilus-actions actions” that will include your new “New Window” option.
```

I found this at:

http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/ubuntu-13-04nautilus-3-6-fix-open-selected-folders-in-new-windows-with-nautilus-actions/